# Can I use System.Web.Optimization toghether with an AMD loader like requireJS?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, amd

Can I use System.Web.Optimization toghether with an AMD loader like requireJS?

I want to combine a lot of little JS files in one download with the new System.Web.Optimization from .net 4.

How does this generated download work toghether with amd loaders like RequireJS or the dojo toolkit loader?

Does anybody has any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as .NET is concerned, `require` is just another script. It knows nothing about what the scripts are doing. There is no reason you can't do this - just make sure you add the scripts in the correct order so dependencies appear first.

There are a few caveats that I discovered while doing something much like this - see my question about caching: [How to force BundleCollection to flush cached script bundles in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317391/how-to-force-bundlecollection-to-flush-cached-script-bundles-in-mvc4)