# How to Change MVC Registered Bundle Collection items Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections, bundle

I wish if i could change registered bundle collection items (JS or CSS files) dynamically after my MVC website published for example by hitting a button. Is it possible and what should we do to achieve this?

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some search and try i found a way. I put this snippet in Session_Start but you can use it any where for example in button submit handler. I search for Bundle with a special name, then remove and create a new bundle with that name that i used in my project. (***I did it to have new fresh bundle because i can't find any method to remove files from existing bundle and i appreciate if anyone knows how to do***) Finally add files to bundle with include method of bundle and add bundle to BundleTable. (*You could use IncludeDirectory method too*)

```
Bundle bndl = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor("~/Content/css");
            if (bndl != null)
            {
                BundleTable.Bundles.Remove(bndl);
            }

            Bundle bndl2 = new Bundle("~/Content/css");
            bndl2.Include("~/Content/site.css", "~/Content/secondStyles.css", ... );
            BundleTable.Bundles.Add(bndl2);
```

At the last it's useful to read this article for working with bundles.
[Asp.net MVC 4 performance optimization with bundling and minification](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/c72b040113-Asp.net-MVC-4-performance-optimization-with-bundling-and-minification.html)

Additional answers appreciated.
Good Luck.

Comment: Just a point to be wary of: because the bundle is cached, making changes to the BundleTable won't immediately change the served bundle. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12324888/792525

Comment: @decates Good point. I read it and I must do some tests. After test and research I'll share results. Thanks again for your heeds.